# convert '[object Object]' to date angular 4

Tags: angular, date, typescript, datepicker, angular-cli

How can i convert '[object Object]'(datepicker) to date format

```
<input type="text"
       id="date"
       class="form-control"
       formControlName="date"
       name="date"
       [(ngModel)]="date"
       ngbDatepicker
       #incorporatedDatePicker="ngbDatepicker"
       (click)="incorporatedDatePicker.toggle()"
       readonly>
```

when i display

```
    {{meeting.date | date }}
```

i have error: invalidPipeArgument Error '[object Object]' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: how does the date look like?

Comment: if i don't add date pipe , it returns [object Object]

Comment: show the date object json

Comment: Please go through this link https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: i don't want it json i want it in date form , when i convert json to date {{meeting.date | json | date:'short'}}  , i have InvalidPipeArgument: '{
  "day": 18,
  "month": 8,
  "year": 2017
}' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Answer (score 6):

For those still looking for an answer to this, you have to use the `NgbDateAdapter` provider like shown in the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#adapter):

```
import { NgbModule, NgbDateAdapter, NgbDateNativeAdapter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: NgbDateAdapter,
    useClass: NgbDateNativeAdapter
  }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then when using `[(ngModel)]="from"` on the input it will automatically use the model as a `Date`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, what you are trying to feed to the `DatePipe` is...

```
{ "day": 18, "month": 8, "year": 2017 }
```

Angular cannot read an object like that and understand that is a date. You need to transform it before to some format that Angular can understand. Formats that are accepted is mentioned in [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

> `date_expression | date[:format]`
>
> `expression` is a date object or a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch) or an ISO string (https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Comment: i still don't know how i transform json to any format that DatePipe accept !

Answer (score 0):

In Component

```
export class DateComponent implements OnInit {
      objDate = Date.now();
}
```

In HTML

```
<strong>{{ objDate | date :'fullDate' }}</strong>
```

OutPut

```
Thursday, February 15, 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{{meeting.date.seconds * 1000 | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with the answer. So that others can understand what's going on. And how it solves problem.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.